# Unable to load KeywordRepeatFilter in Solr 4.4

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm using the version 4.4 of Apache Solr. As specified in [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

> ```
> <fieldType name="text_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
>  <analyzer>
>    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
>    <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilter"/>
>    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
>    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
>  </analyzer>
> </fieldType>
> ```

I am using the above code. But there seems to be some issue with the "KeywordRepeatFilter" as I am getting the error

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_keyword": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.KeywordRepeatFilter'
>       at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:177)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:467)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.(IndexSchema.java:164)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)

But when I removed the solr.KeywordRepeatFilter line, everything seems to work fine.
Can anyone pls tell me what is wrong. Is the "solr.KeywordRepeatFilter" been removed from Solr 4.4 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need to include KeywordRepeatFilterFactory instead of KeywordRepeatFilter.